# How to solve background color strips in linear-gradient?

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

I don't want pattern, but simple linear-gradient.

But, By using following code I have got a background pattern strips.

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient( to top, #ffffff, #e6e6e6);
}
```

Checkout : [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1hNk.png)

Comment: Add Proper code, if possible add working snippet

Comment: What is the desired effect?

Comment: right now the gradient keeps stopping and starting again he wants one smooth gradient

Comment: @L_Church Thanks, think it's a duplicate

Comment: yes, correct ...@L_Church

Comment: Actually, I was a li' confused  of how to ask this question.. @All

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient( to top, #ffffff, #e6e6e6);
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

From the linked question, this stops the background from repeating and sets the height of the graphic to 100% so it's not just one line

Comment: Thanks, @L_Church

Answer (score 2):

You don't have any contents and no height, that's the reason for the stripes. Add height or contents, that will do it.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background: linear-gradient( to top, #ffffff, #e6e6e6);
}
```

Comment: heh two answers same result. take this one it looks better to me

Comment: ... or refer to the duplicate question.

Comment: the dupe question is basically mine but this does it with less